# How to effectively save referenced class type in Python? (appengine)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'd like to refer to different classes in a persistent appengine Model. Like:

```
class Animal():
  def eat(self, food):
    return food - 1

class Cat(Animal):
  def eat(self, food):
    return food - 2

class Dog(Animal):
  def eat(self, food):
    return food - 3

class Person(db.Model):
  name = db.StringProperty()
  pet = Animal()
```

I want to be able to assign either a Cat() or Dog() instance as a pet, save it and be able to reload a Person object with the original type of animal referenced in it. Persistance for the pet objects are not important, I only want to define different sets of behaviours with the methods of the classes. How do I do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Does `Animal` subclass `db.Model` or is it exactly as you put here? If `Animal` is a model class, then you could use a `ReferenceProperty` to `Animal` in `Person`.

Comment: Nope, that is why I stated that the Animal class and its children are not persistent. I guess making the Animal class a db.Model or db.PolyModel will not solve the issue without any persistent variables.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [PolyModel](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/polymodelclass) class.

Comment: To my understanding PolyModel will return the type of class that you define in the **query** itself. Animal.all() will return common variables (which I don't have any) of both Dog and Cat records, but the methods will be of Animal(). I want to be able to access the Dog and Cat specific methods thru the persistent Person object.

Answer (score 0):

The best I can come up with myself is a getter method (assuming the above Animal, Cat, Dog classes):

```
class Person(db.Model):
  name = StringProperty()
  pet = StringProperty(choices=('cat','dog'))

  def get_pet(self):
    dict = { 'cat': Cat, 'dog': Dog }
    return dict[self.pet]
```

This way I have to maintain the list of available pet types in two additional places (choices for the saved string variable and the dictionary of string-class pairs). Is there a more risk free and elegant way to do this?